# Java string capitalize and fix errors

Tags: java, capitalize

I want to check my string to capitalize errors.(Have 16.000+ line) And some lines have capitalize error. If special characters(?, !, . etc..) after character start with lowercase or word have some uppercase character. ***(Strings have turkish characters)***

**Target string;**

> **i**ki o**RD**u Eskihisar'da karşılaştı ve Orhan Gazi, Bizanslıları denize **dÖkErek** büyük bir zafer kazandı.  **o**smanlılar 1331'de
>   İznik'i, 1337'de İzmit'i topraklarına kattı! **izmit**'in
>   fethedilmesiyle Bizans'ın Anadolu'daki varlığı **Son** buldu.

**I want this;**

> **İ**ki **ordu** Eskihisar'da karşılaştı ve Orhan Gazi, Bizanslıları denize **dökerek** büyük bir zafer kazandı. **O**smanlılar 1331'de
>   İznik'i, 1337'de İzmit'i topraklarına kattı! **İzmit**'in
>   fethedilmesiyle Bizans'ın Anadolu'daki varlığı **son** buldu.

When i was use `StringUtils.capitalize(org.apache library)` doesnt work when turkish character...

I can do this in java?

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: I tried but I could pretty

Comment: Yes, you can do this in Java. Iterate the string and apply your logic, using methods like [`Character.isUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28int%29). *(Ok, maybe I'm assuming too much. It can be done in Java. Whether you can do it, depends on your skill level, but it shouldn't be that difficult)*

Comment: I don't see the logic in what you expect actually, in the middle of a sentence you can have words starting with capital letter and other not, could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes i know thats is not difficult if i use only uppercase :) But my capitalize operation complex. Some times comma, dot other special character after white space one or more times etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringUtils.capitalize` is not the right candidate for you as If you have a capital letter in the middle of the word, it will remain in capital letter which is not what you want obviously.

Here is how it could be implemented:

```
int length = value.length();
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
boolean sentence = false;
boolean space = false;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = value.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case ',' :
        case '.' :
        case '?' :
        case '!' :
            sentence = false;
            space = false;
            buffer.append(c);
            break;
        case ' ' :
            if (!space) {
                space = true;
                buffer.append(c);
            }
            break;
        case '\t' :
            space = false;
            buffer.append(c);
            break;
        default:
            if (sentence) {
                buffer.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            } else {
                buffer.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            }
            sentence = true;
            space = false;
    }
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

**Output:**

```
Iki ordu eskihisar'da karşılaştı ve orhan gazi, Bizanslıları denize dökerek büyük bir zafer 
kazandı. Osmanlılar 1331'de iznik'i, 1337'de izmit'i topraklarına 
kattı! Izmit'in fethedilmesiyle bizans'ın anadolu'daki varlığı son 
buldu. Topraklarına Kattı! Izmit'in Fethedilmesiyle Bizans'ın 
Anadolu'daki Varlığı Son Buldu.
```

Comment: If two or more space  than what can i do :) for example `"kazandı.  space space space    osmanlılar"` > `"kazandı. Osmanlılar"`

Comment: you have two spaces between the two words?

Comment: its possible between the words and two or more spaces after ?, !, comma or dot etc

Comment: With my code above if you have "kazandı.   osmanlılar", you will get "kazandı.   Osmanlılar", it is not what you want? you want to remove the extra spaces?

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: "kazandı.[space][space][space]osmanlılar" after your codes > "kazandı.[space][space][space]Osmanlılar" extra space problem here.

Comment: and what do you expect ?

Comment: i want to "kazandı.[space]Osmanlılar" and i solve with this code `buffer.toString().replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ");` thank you

Comment: try this new version